Seeking Flutter Video Player with DRM Support for HLS Playback
I'm developing a Flutter application that requires video playback with two key functionalities:
1. Digital Rights Management (DRM): To safeguard content security, I need a video player that integrates with DRM solutions like Widevine or FairPlay.
2. HLS (HTTP Live Streaming): The video source is delivered using the HLS protocol for efficient streaming.
Crucial Question:
Are there any readily available Flutter video player packages that effectively combine DRM support with HLS playback capabilities? If so, any recommendations or guidance on implementation would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Considerations:
If there's no single solution that offers both features, I'm open to exploring alternative approaches, such as:

Third-party libraries or plugins that provide DRM integration.
Platform-specific (Android/iOS) native video player integration with
DRM support.


Did you find any package that has DRM support? What did you end up using, can you share?

@Sandra , I ended up using a WebView to display the video player as a temporary solution. I'm still investigating DRM support and exploring other options. I'll make sure to share any updates once I find a more permanent solution!
